# How to check if the working copy is clean using pysvn?

Tags: python, svn, pysvn

I want to use `pysvn` to determine the revision of a working copy and whether its contents are identical to those in the repository (for the same revision).

Getting the revision number was no problem, but how can I find out whether there are any uncommitted changes in the working copy. So what I am looking for the equivalent of checking whether `svn status --ignore-externals` has no lines not starting with `X`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to do it using:

```
def has_no_modifications(path_to_repository)
    statuses = client.status(path_to_repository, ignore=True, recurse=True)
    statuses = [s for s in statuses if s.data['text_status'] != pysvn.wc_status_kind.normal]
    return len(statuses) == 0
```